# Node.js + Express Sessions: How to keep track of date and time of last visit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session

I was wondering how one would be able to keep track of a user's last visit on a site with Express? For example:

1.User visits site for the first time, receives a welcome.

2.The next time user visits site, it will display the date and time of their last visit.

I've looked into the Express sessions documentation but I didn't see a solution for dealing with this.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Express sessions combined with the cookies to get this effect.

> ```
> var express = require('express');
> var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
> var session = require('express-session');
>
> var app = express();
>
> app.use(cookieParser());
> app.use(session({secret: "Shh, its a secret!"}));
>
> app.get('/', function(req, res){
>    if(req.session.page_views){
>       req.session.page_views++;
>       res.send("You visited this page " + req.session.page_views + " times");
>    } else {
>       req.session.page_views = 1;
>       res.send("Welcome to this page for the first time!");
>    }
> });
> app.listen(3000);
> ```

[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_sessions.htm) is the tutorial.

The best is to understand how the sessions work by exploiting HTTP cookies.